# PDE solution positivity constraint

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

I have a 2d PDE and NDSolve returns a solution that takes negative values but I want the function to be positive

```
     f[x,y]>=0
```

everywhere. How do I include this simple constraint?

Comment: The sign of the solution will be defined by the initial and boundary conditions and the range over which you integrate. Therefore, you have to adjust these to get a solution with f>0.

Comment: is there no way of including this constraint?

Comment: You are not free to specify this. It is given be the afore mentioned parameters and of course the equation. Another question would be, if you are searching these parameters.

Comment: its a physical problem, I understand its not a mathematically 100% well-posed PDE but I dont think NDSolve is so strict

Comment: If physics requests f>0, then I think either the equations or inital/boundary conditions are wrong. And it is also possible that you have a problem with numerical stability.  And of course the possibility exists, that you are on the brink to detect new physics.

Comment: @VN23 Also we can't tell you nothing without PDE, boundary conditions and code you try to solve your problem with.